# Disabling caldav reminders in iPhone

Tags: iphone, caldav

I am writing a caldav server for our company which will be compatible with a number of clients, one of the key supported devices will be iPhone running iOS 4+.

This server will only support VEVENTs however when the server is initially configured under settings in the iPhone, the iPhone thinks that the server also supports VTODOs. As there is no VTODO calendar outlined, it then proceeds to try to create a default one on my server. The Warning in the console output reads: “This account is enabled for tasks, but has no task calendar. We’re going to create a default one” I return that MKCALENDAR request with an empty response with 403 status, however the phone doesn’t seem to realise it’s failed and still puts the Reminder list in the Reminders app. I’m not where I should be flagging to the phone that this account is not enabled for tasks.

I haven’t been able to find much information on caldav servers in general and none on what iOS supports and is expecting from a server. I have been adhering to the standards in multiple RFCs including 4791, 5545, 3744 and 4918 but have not been able to find any help for this particular issue. I have also looked through the developer resources provided by apple to no avail.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Jo

Answer (score 0):

We needed to support serving iCalendar events to iOS as well, and struggled with some of these issues. For our problem, the calendar was read-only to our target clients (which I'm guessing is likely not true for yours). The server task was dramatically simplified when we realized we could use the subscribed calendars option to just get a calendar feed without anything else:

[image]

Not exactly a direct answer to your problem, but hopefully useful as an option to consider.

Comment: Thanks ckhan! Great to hear you had success with subscribed calendars. I had been thinking we could use this for our primary calendar for clients which is read-only, which will be fine for now. You are right though that we are ultimately looking for a read-write solution for other calendars we were hoping to provide.